# Windows 10 batch file - test if directory exists, copy file, beep on error

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, file-exists

I've been looking at many posts on this site to see what I'm doing wrong, but I can't get this simple script to work.

The script is stored in my %MyDocuments%\IT\scripts\ folder, which is in my PATH. I CD to the folder that I want to run the script from then call it and pass a photo number, i.e.

```
r5 0893
```

If the folder .\Rejects does not exist, I need to create it. Then it tries to move the file to the Rejects subfolder, and I'd like to beep if the copy failed, e.g. I've put in a photo number that doesn't exist.

```
:: echo off
if exist Rejects 
(
    echo Rejects\ found, goto DirectoryExists
    goto DirectoryExists
)
else
(
    echo Creating Rejects\ folder
    mkdir Rejects 
)
:DirectoryExists
:: pause
echo if not exist 2X9A%1.jpg
if not exist 2X9A%1.jpg
(
    echo "File 2X9A%1.jpg not found!!!"
    rundll32 user32.dll,MessageBeep
)
Else
(
    echo move 2X9A%1.jpg To Rejects\
    move 2X9A%1.jpg Rejects\
)
:: pause
```

Furthermore, these commands work one at a time from the command prompt, but not from the batch file! :

```
D:\Photos\2018\1.06. Leyla>r5 0489
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
D:\Photos\2018\1.06. Leyla>if exist Rejects
D:\Photos\2018\1.06. Leyla>if exist Rejects echo Yes
Yes
```

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Open up a command prompt and type `IF /?` to read the help file. You will see plain as day what the syntax problem is.

Comment: Hi @Compo, the batch file is called r5.bat, so `r5 0893` sets %1 = 0893. Re `Rejects` vs `Rejects\`, I had tried both, including `Rejects\nul` from another thread here.

Comment: To make the computer beep, you don't need `RunDll` -- just use: `echo <ctrl+G>` (where you actually type **Ctrl+G**). Doesn't work in Notepad but works eg from `copy con beep.bat` if you want a stand-alone beeping batch file. Use Alt+0007 (on the keypad) as another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has to be fixed like this:

```bat
@echo off

if exist Rejects (
    echo Rejects\ found, going to DirectoryExists
    goto DirectoryExists
) else (
    echo Creating Rejects\ folder
    mkdir Rejects 
)

:DirectoryExists
rem pause
echo if not exist 2X9A%1.jpg

if not exist 2X9A%1.jpg (
    echo "File 2X9A%1.jpg not found!"
    rundll32 user32.dll,MessageBeep
) else (
    echo move 2X9A%1.jpg To Rejects\
    move 2X9A%1.jpg Rejects\
)

pause
```

You seem to program in low/medium level languages. However, this is the default syntax for `if` in batch file.

Type `if /?` in `cmd.exe` to learn more about its syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that you've accepted an answer, which shows you how to use an `If` / `Else` statement, but I think you should really consider rearranging the script like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
If "%~1"=="" Exit /B
If Not Exist "2X9A%~1.jpg" (
    Echo "File 2X9A%~1.jpg not found!!!"
    Rundll32 User32.dll,MessageBeep
    Pause
    Exit /B
)
If Not Exist "Rejects\" (
    Echo Creating Rejects directory
    MD "Rejects" 2>Nul || Exit /B
)
Echo Moving 2X9A%1.jpg to Rejects directory
Move /Y "2X9A%1.jpg" "Rejects"
Pause
```

*The idea being that you don't create a possibly missing directory, if the file doesn't exist; (this will also help if the current directory isn't what you were expecting). I've also added the trailing backslash necessary to ensure that the existence check is against a directory not a file named `Rejects`. You'll also note that I've removed the `Else` statements, because they weren't really needed.*